# Inline includes for httpd.conf?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, deny

Let's say I have a file list_of_naughty_ip_blocks.conf. Can I use the include directive to achieve the equivalent of line 8 below in my httpd.conf? If so, what is the proper syntax? Anything to note about the formatting & syntax of list_of_naughty_ip_blocks.conf?

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FNetwork" UnwantedRobot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "NG 1.x" UnwantedRobot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "larbin" UnwantedRobot

<Directory "/var/www/">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=UnwantedRobot
    Deny from "list_of_naughty_ip_blocks.conf"
</Directory>
```

Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Just have the "Deny from" keyphrase in the include file:

```
<Location /secret/>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from env=UnwantedRobot
  Include conf.d/moredeny.inc
</Location>
```

In moredeny.inc

```
Deny from 192.168.1.1
Deny from 192.168.66.1
Deny from 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include

Comment: Yes, I read that but it didn't directly answer my question, which is about the syntax. I take it you think what I proposed will work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

A 'dirty' way is use `sed` to append a line after `env=UnwantedRobot` pattern. Assuming that you have the following in `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=UnwantedRobot
</Directory>
```

and the `ip.txt` file includes:

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
```

run the following command:

```
$ while read ip; do sed -i '/env=UnwantedRobot/ a\ 
                    \tDeny\ from\ '"$ip"'' httpd.conf; done < ip.txt
```

you will get the results:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=UnwantedRobot
    Deny from 5.6.7.8
    Deny from 1.2.3.4
</Directory>
```

- `-i` means edit file in place
- `a` stand for append

Comment: I think you could just include a file containing all the `Deny from a.b.c.d` after the `Deny from env=UnwantedRobot`

Comment: How do you do? `Include` directive only allows inclusion of configuration files.